# How to create custom theme a view

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I've defined a view with the `CCK` and `View 2 modules`. i have two way for print result. 1- with the **"Node"** 2 - with the **"fields"** .

1. if i choose node Content, i'd choose view mode. per default is
   (teaser, rss, ....). now,

**question 1** - how to create new custom view
   node theme?i.e :new teaser / teaserOne/ etc ... (put in dropdown menu)

1. if i choose fields content, i see in theme information(advanced
   Menu) this data: `*NOTE: (this data for prompted in front page block)*`

   - **Display output**: views-view.tpl.php, views-view--frontpage.tpl.php,
     views-view--default.tpl.php, views-view--default.tpl.php,
     views-view--page.tpl.php, views-view--frontpage--page.tpl.php
   - **Style output**: views-view-unformatted.tpl.php,
     views-view-unformatted--frontpage.tpl.php,
     views-view-unformatted--default.tpl.php,
     views-view-unformatted--default.tpl.php,
     views-view-unformatted--page.tpl.php,
     views-view-unformatted--frontpage--page.tpl.php
   - **Row style output**: views-view-fields.tpl.php,
     views-view-fields--frontpage.tpl.php,
     views-view-fields--default.tpl.php,
     views-view-fields--default.tpl.php, views-view-fields--page.tpl.php,
     views-view-fields--frontpage--page.tpl.php

**question 2**: how to create custom theme for print result using fields methods?

please tell me step by step.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: I think what you're looking for is [entity view modes module.](http://drupal.org/project/entity_view_mode)

I'm not sure what you mean with the second question.